# Using a static const member from static non-member function

Tags: c++, class, static-members

I have a private static const member in class, and in the class implementation I have static function that tries to use this const, but it gives me errors.

```
//A.hpp
class A {
    static const int X = 1;     //<<problem here
    // ....
}
```

and I have

```
//A.cpp
static int DoSomething();
// ....
static int DoSomething {
    int n = A::X;           //<<problem here
        //....
}
```

and I get `within this context` when I try to use X from `DoSomething` and `‘const int A::X’ is private` in the `static const int X = 1;`.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please post some syntactically valid C++ code.

Comment: Maybe you should change it to `public: static const int X = 1;`

Comment: Is `A.hpp` something important or it's just a typing mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access a private member of `A` from a free function. This is not allowed.

You should make it `public`, eg:

```
class A {
public:
  static const int X = 1;
}
```

Comment: But I don't want it to be public... it's for use only inside the class

Comment: You are trying to access it from outside the class since DoSomething is not part of the class, so your requirement is not met.

Comment: Alternatively declare `DoSomething` as a `friend` of `class A`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to Jack's answer is to make the function `DoSomething()` non-static and declare it as a `friend` of class A:

```
//A.hpp
class A {
    static const int X = 1;
    // ....

    friend int DoSomething();
 };

//A.cpp
int DoSomething() {
    int n = A::X;
      //....
}
```